# How to solve an error in label_eurostat(): "Dictionary information is missing"

Tags: r, dictionary, label

I periodically download a dataset from eurostat with the eurostat package in R and label it with the function label_eurostat(). The following code just worked fine in the past but gives me some errors since this week:

```
> emprt <- get_eurostat("lfst_r_lfe2emprt", time_format = "num")
> emprt <- filter(emprt, sex == "T", age == "Y15-64", geo %in% c("AT", "DE", "FR"))
> emprt <- dcast(emprt, geo ~ time)
Using values as value column: use value.var to override.
> emprt <- label_eurostat(emprt, lang = "de")
Error in label_eurostat(emprt, lang = "de") :
 Dictionary information is missing
```

I also tried a specific dictionary but received another warning message:

```
> emprt <- label_eurostat(emprt, dic = "geo", lang = "de")
Warning message:
In label_eurostat(emprt, dic = "geo", lang = "de") :
  All labels for geo were not found.
```

I´m not sure if the dictionary is the one to choose but it was the only one I found at eurostat.
I also saw that there are some other issues with this function causing an error like this:

```
Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : 
factor level [19] is duplicated
```

But I´m not sure if this one is related to my Problem.
I´m thankfull for every hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
packageVersion("eurostat")
# [1] ‘3.1.1’
library(eurostat)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
get_eurostat("lfst_r_lfe2emprt", time_format = "num") %>%
  filter(sex == "T", age == "Y15-64", geo %in% c("AT", "DE", "FR")) %>%
  dcast(geo ~ time) %>%
  droplevels %>%
  mutate(geo = label_eurostat(geo, dic = "geo", lang = "de"))
```

or

```
get_eurostat("lfst_r_lfe2emprt", time_format = "num") %>%
  filter(sex == "T", age == "Y15-64", geo %in% c("AT", "DE", "FR")) %>%
  label_eurostat(lang = "de") %>%
  dcast(geo ~ time)
```

With regards to the warning: If you don't drop unused `geo` factor levels, `label_eurostat` might assign duplicate labels; for instance consider

```
get_eurostat("lfst_r_lfe2emprt", time_format = "num") %>% 
  pull(geo) %>% 
  levels %>% 
  grep(pattern = "^DE3", value = TRUE)
# [1] "DE3"  "DE30"
```

If you now look at `get_eurostat_dic("geo")`, both `DE3` and `DE30` lead to `Berlin`:

```
get_eurostat_dic("geo") %>% filter(grepl("^DE30?$", code_name))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   code_name full_name
#       <chr>     <chr>
# 1       DE3    Berlin
# 2      DE30    Berlin
```

Side note: You don't need `reshape2::dcast` if you got the tidyverse loaded; you could also do `select(geo, time, values) %>% spread(time, values)` instead.